# Is it possible to Update UI from 2 background workers

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am working on a WPF application using C# and I wanted to implement a second background worker object. I already have 1 that works the way I want it to.

This first background worker updates a progress bar based on some operations.
I want the second to update a text block which displays a countdown timer.

First off, is this possible to do?
Currently, When the timer counts down and reaches zero, when the other thread tries to access the progress bar, it gives an error.

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Here is the code for my background workers:
In the main window method I initialize them.

```
        // Add the background worker events
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        worker_timer.DoWork += worker_TrackTime;
        worker_timer.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_TimeCompleted;
        worker_timer.ProgressChanged += worker_timerProgressChanged;
        worker_timer.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Here are the thread methods:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Run all background tasks here
        copyEverything(sourceFolder, targetFolder);
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update UI once worker complete his work
        // Update the progress bar and progress percent text to the max value it can be
        copy_progressbar.Value = copy_progressbar.Maximum;
        copy_textblock.Text = copy_progressbar.Maximum + "%";

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted -= new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update something here
        copy_progressbar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        copy_textblock.Text = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";

        // Check if the progressbar has reached its maximum value, if so set the value to its max
        if (copy_progressbar.Value >= copy_progressbar.Maximum)
        {
            copy_progressbar.Value = copy_progressbar.Maximum;
            copy_textblock.Text = copy_progressbar.Maximum + "%";
        }
    }

    private void worker_TimeCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void worker_TrackTime(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            elapsedTS = elapsedTS.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
            try
            {
                worker_timer.ReportProgress(1);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            if (elapsedTS >= schedule.TS)
            {
                copyEverythingAsync(sourceFolder, targetFolder);
                schedule.updateSchedule(DateTime.Now, false);
                schedule.checkSchedule();
                checkScheduleTime();

                elapsedTS = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }
    }

    private void worker_timerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        time_left_textblock.Text = "" + schedule.TS.Subtract(elapsedTS).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
        //time_left_textblock.Text = "" + schedule.TS.Subtract(elapsedTS).ToString();
    }
```

The thread that tracks the timer does not have a completed method because I want it to continually run.

I can put more info if needed.

Comment: Pass the elapsedTS in the ProgressChangedEventArgs e.   Don't try and access it directly.

Comment: Always check for errors in the Completed event.

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with the number of background workers. Your title implies that this problem arises because this is the 2nd work. But in fact, the problem is, that you're trying to update the UI - if you only had 1 background worker that was doing this, you'd see the same error. As Mayank points out, that you need to dispatch back to the UI thread to update the UI.

Comment: @IanGriffiths The whole *point* of a BGW is to marshal to the UI thread on your behalf for all oft he event handlers besides the `DoWork` event.  So no, you don't "always need to dispatch back to the UI thread manually".

Comment: You shouldn't be using a BGW to run some code after a period of time.  You should use a `Timer` for that.  Since that is the tool specifically designed for the job you're trying to do, you'll find it much easier to work with.  As for the error you're seeing, you haven't shown enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Servy it doesn't marshal back to the UI thread if you just try to update the UI directly from within the `DoWork` handler. It only marshals progress and completion notifications. RXC says "the other thread tries to access the progress bar, it gives an error." It's not actually clear where that's happening, because the question doesn't show where the exception actually occurs. But in any event "the other thread" should not in any event be attempting to access the UI, even if you are using a BGW.

Comment: @EliArbel - That might have been my problem. I call RunWorkerAsync from a method that is called by the timer thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the UI using UI thread.

```
   private void worker_timerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
       {
          time_left_textblock.Text = "" + schedule.TS.Subtract(elapsedTS).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
       });
    }
```

Comment: It says Invoke does not exists in the current context. Am I missing a namespace?

Comment: call `Dispatcher.Invoke` for WPF

Comment: Your answer worked. I just had to use the Dispather.Invoke on the other thread as well when it tries to update the UI. Thanks

Comment: The whole *point* of using a BGW is so that it will marshal the non-work events to the UI thread on your behalf so you don't *need* to do things like this.

Comment: @Servy what would be more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: @Mayank Well, for starters, use a `Timer` to run code every second, not a BGW.  Not enough code is shown to understand why the BGW is unsuccessfully marshaling to the UI thread.